# Trying to give the object correct parameters

Tags: java

So I am attempting a project with a fake credit card to get a feel of coding but I am at a stop because the code I input gives me "cannot find symbol" errors. Am I doing this wrong?

```
 class Main{
  float balance;
  String name;
  public void card(String name, float balance){
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;

  }
  public static void main(String[] args){

   card test = new card("Name", 3000.0);
   System.out.printlm(test);

  //  Card cards = new Card();
  //  cards.example();
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
   card test = new card("Name", 3000.0);
   ^
  symbol:   class card
  location: class Main
Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
   card test = new card("Name", 3000.0);
                   ^
  symbol:   class card
  location: class Main
2 errors
compiler exit status 1
```

Comment: You didn't define a constructor. Constructors have no return type

Comment: I am brand new to coding and honestly I thought I put a constructor. Could you give me an example/template of how it should look please?

Comment: You also don't have a class named `card`, so you'd get an error even if you'd properly defined its constructor.  You can't make a new instance of a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: I feel that you are mixing methods and classes. Define a *Card* class instead of trying to call a method call *card*.

Answer (score 4):

You passed the parameters fine, but your class constructor name must match the class and have no return type (remove void)

Classes should also always start with a capital letter

```
public class Card {
  float balance;
  String name;

  public Card(String name, float balance){
      this.name = name;
      this.balance = balance;
  }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     Card test = new Card("Name", 3000.0);
     System.out.println(test.name);
 }
}
```

This should be saved as `Card.java`

Comment: I'd also suggest using an IDE rather than a plain text file and compiling from the command line

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the idea of constructors much better now! I am using repl.it because I'm practicing at work and don't have access or permission for an actual IDE sadly.

Comment: With some effort, Eclipse Che could be setup as a personal web IDE